# Machine representation in fl(x) given x

Tags: numerical-methods, machine-precision

Im having a debate between me and my study group regarding a question of numerical representation.

$x = 0.002718281828459$, $\beta = 10$, $p = 6$ We are told to find $\text{fl}(x)$,
$\beta$ is base and $p$ is precision just to clarify. I found the answer to be:
$\text{fl}(x) = 271.828 \times 10^{-3}$  and the $\text{error} = .1828459 \times 10^{-7}$.

They have: $\text{fl}(x) = 2.71828 \times 10^{-5}$ with an $\text{error} = .1828459 \times 10^{-8}$

My study group believes it be okay to truncate the two leading zeros after the decimal point so their $x$ value is $.2718281828459$. I contend that that changes the value of the entity and is therefore wrong.

The rationale for my argument is that, you move the decimal 6 places starting where it is at and you get $271.XXX$ with $p = 6$ you need a total of $6$ digits, the first three are $271$, the next are $.828$ The values of $10^{-3}$ is from the amount of digits after $271$ of which there are three, and the $10^{-7}$ is form the position of the leading value in $.1828459$.

Comment: $271.828\times 10^{-3}$ isn't even near your given $x$. Did you mean to write $10^{-5}$ instead of $10^{-3}$?

Comment: Also, please explain the meaning of the function $fl()$

Comment: If your $\operatorname{fl}$ is defined as $\operatorname{fl}(x) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^p m_k \beta^{-k}\right)\beta^{e}$ such that the error $\min_{(m_1,\dots,m_k)\in\{0,\dots,\beta-1\}^p,e\in\mathbb N} |fl(x) - x|$ is minimized then $\operatorname{fl}(x)= .271828\times 10^{-2}$ with an exact error $.1828459\times 10^{-8}$.

Comment: @Wauzl yes i did mean $10^{-5}$

Comment: Please edit your question then. Also the error of your exponent should be $-8$, as well. I think both solutions are correct, but usually the mantissa in computers are the digits after the "$0.$" together with the correct exponent. See my previous comment. But we still don't know how your teacher defined $\operatorname fl$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is insufficient information to determine the floating point representation of the number $x$. To that end, we require the permitted range of exponents.

It is entirely possible to select a range of exponents, such that $x$ can only be represented as a subnormal number with less than $p$ significant figures, see below.

As we are only given the base $\beta=10$ and the precision $p=6$, the real issue is to round $x$ correctly. A useful first step is to write $x = 0.002718281828459$ using normalized scientific notation, i.e.,
$$ x = 2.718281828459 \times 10^{-3}.$$
This immediately reveals the magnitude of $x$ and we can count 13 significant figures. We now round $x$ to $p=6$ significant figures and obtain
$$\bar{x} = 2.71828 \times 10^{-3}.$$
The error is
$$x - \bar{x} = 0.000001828459 \times 10^{-3} = 1.828459 \times 10^{-9}.$$

Now suppose that our hypothetical computer has a smallest exponent of 0. Then $x$ is substantially smaller than $1$, our smallest positive normal floating point number and we must either flush $x$ to zero or use a subnormal number to represent $x$, i.e. 
$$ \hat{x} = 0.00272 \times 10^0.$$
Here 3 figures of the significand have been sacrificed to allow for a nonzero representation of $x$.